# Set html file as folder main page

Tags: html, cpanel, host

i want to set html file as main page in folder. for example if file.html hosts here - www.domain.com/folder/file.html so the address will be only www.domain.com/folder. maybe someone know how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name it index.html (in most webhosting services it is the name of the default file).